# many log files on azure service fabric

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have a azure service fabric development cluster running locally with two applications.

After a two week holiday I come back and see that my hard drive is completely full, consequently nothing really works anymore.

the sfdevcluster\log\traces folder has many *.etl files all larger than 100MB.
And all kinds of other log files > 250 MB are present

So my questions: how to disable tracing/logging on azure service fabric and are there tools to administer log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Service Fabric, upgrade your local cluster to the latest version `6.1.472.9494` which will fix the issue. [more details here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/677#issuecomment-356124446)

Answer (score 3):

The powerShell script file that does the cluster setup magic is:

```
Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1
```

Looking inside, there is a function called `DeployNodeConfiguration` which sets the logs and data path using the PowerShell command `New-ServiceFabricNodeConfiguration`. Unfortunately, It does not seem that there is a way to limit the size of those folders.

I believe that your slowness / freeze is due to insufficient space on the OS drive (happened to me too haha). A workaround can be to set the location of those folders to a non-OS drive with a limited amount of space.

Hope this helps

Comment: Moving it to a data drive fixed it. The script also removes the old cluster so thats nice. The cluster was using 120 GB space...