# Azure Service Fabric - Large Trace Logs Folder

Tags: azure-service-fabric

**Azure Service Fabric Cluster:** 5 Windows Nodes, 29 Applications
**Fabric Version:** 6.1.472.9494

- Applications report unhealthy due to lack of disk space on the data drive.
- The \SvcFab\Log\Traces folder was consuming about 80GB of the available 99GB.
- This folder contained a very large number of .etl files in the following naming format fabric_traces_6.1.472.9494_131695673562955183_2.etl.
- The Trace folders on all other nodes were less than 5GB.

This issue has happened twice over the past month. Both times it was only one node.

I found [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763013/many-log-files-on-azure-service-fabric) from 2016 for the same problem
The accepted answer mentions that this was fixed in 6.1.472.9494, however I'm still experiencing this problem.

The accepted answer also contained a link to the Service-Fabric-Issues Github. [This comment](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/677#issuecomment-357386857) mentions a workaround using SF-FolderCleaner. The last comment states that version 6.1.467 fixes this issue.

Is this still a known issue? Is the best path forward to implement the SF-FolderCleaner workaround?

Comment: Did you configure the quota? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings

  ```{
    "name": "Diagnostics",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "MaxDiskQuotaInMB",
        "value": "65536"
      }
    ]
  }```

Comment: @LoekD Thank you for replying. I have not set the MaxDiskQuotaInMB parameter for my cluster. According to that link, the default is 65536 MB. The \SvcFab\Log\Traces folder on my node was 80 GB alone. Does this parameter only apply to the Traces folder? I couldn't find any information on potential performance impact to enabling a disk quota.

Comment: @TylerHenrichs Does killing FabricDCA.exe on that node cause the extra files to be cleaned up?  It sounds like issue where DCA is stuck and not operating properly.  The 6.1.467 bug was a configuration issue, where traces wouldn't be cleaned up on all nodes of the cluster.

Comment: I ended up setting the MaxDiskQuotaInMB to 5120 as a test to see if it would force any cleanup. This didn't appear to have any effect. The SvcFab/Log folder size continued to grow.

@Matt Thank you for the reply! I killed the Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Data Collection Agent (FabricDCA.exe) process, and after about 10 minutes the SvcFab/Log folder size went down to 10 GB and remained there for over an hour. I checked again this morning and it is now around 4 GB. Do you know what folders/files are considered when using the MaxDiskQuotaInMB property or what interval the cleanup occurs?

Comment: I think MaxDiskQuotaInMB is considered a dynamic configuration change for SF where the process doesn't restart when it is applied.  I think there must be a bug in FabricDCA.exe where it's cleanup thread is no longer running, but the process is still alive.